# Authentication through Linux Host

Tags: linux, authentication, express, npm

Im experimenting with Node and Express, is there a npm module to authenticate to the password file on the Linux host when I send a password and username through a web form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `authenticate-pam` npm module, also make sure to install the `libpam0g-dev` package on your Linux host.